# Program fails with: write tcp broken pipe error

Tags: go, ftp, pipe

I've got a go app that downloads files using github.com/jlaffaye/ftp which is a library that implements File Transfer Protocol (FTP)

Defined a struct with an FTP connection

```
type Client struct {
    conn *ftp.ServerConn
    sync.Mutex
}
```

I have a global client

```
var cli *Client = nil
```

Which I then initialize and assign to the global variable to be used later

```
    conn, err := ftp.Dial(cfg.Host+cfg.Port, ftp.DialWithContext(ctx))
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("ftp dial error: %v", err)
    }

    err = conn.Login(cfg.Username, pwd)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("ftp login error: %v", err)
    }

    c := &Client{}

    c.Lock()
    c.conn = conn
    cli = c
    c.Unlock()
```

I've got a http handler that takes the conn field from the Client struct and calls

```
    fileNames, err := conn.NameList(".")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

Most of the time, the application fails on the call to `conn.NameList(".")` with error

```
write tcp xxx.xxx.xx.x:48572-\u003exx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21: write: broken pipe
```

And sometimes

```
write tcp xxx.xxx.xx.xx:63037-\u003exx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21: wsasend: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

I don't close the connection prematurely.
Does anyone have an idea on why this is happening? Or maybe you could recommend a better library that uses FTP?

As per the question if multiple services are running at the same time, and if it's conccurently safe.

When a process is running, another can't run until `setIsRunning(false) is called`

```
func (s *Service) setIsRunning(b bool) error {
    mu := &sync.Mutex{}
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()

    if b && s.isRunning {
        return errors.New("already running")
    }
    s.isRunning = b

    return nil
}
```

An attempt to call that handler while its running will yield
`"error":"already running"`

Also I use mutex locks while reading from the global `Client` like such

```
    cli.Lock()
    conn = cli.conn
    cli.Unlock()
```

Comment: Are there multiple requests served using that connection? Is that connection thread-safe?

Comment: @BurakSerdar, Only one request runs at a time, and also I've got mutex locks while using the global `Client`

Comment: @BurakSerdar added some more clarification on your questions in the problem description

Comment: `setIsRunning` is wrong. Your mutex is local, it is not protecting anything.  Put the mutex in `s`.

Comment: @BurakSerdar it seems switching to a non-global client does the trick. I have methods the type receiver being `cli *Client` 
This is also correct, right?

Answer (score 0):

switching to a non-global client resolves the issue